# Trouble with sticky footer

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I can't seem to get my sticky footer working. It's my understanding after some research that the parent element of the footer needs to be set to position: relative. Then the footer should be set to position: absolute with bottom: 0. I've done that and it looks fine fullscreen. But when the browser is resized to be smaller, the footer sits in the middle of the page. Any advice? I've been searching for about an hour with no luck. Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, I'd like for the footer to only be visible once you scroll to the bottom of the page or if the whole page is in view. Not persistent on the page at all times (position: fixed.)

```
(Please see the codepen link below)
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/rmcguinn/pen/LOMGYY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `min-height: 100%;` to the overarching div/body.  You will also need to add `padding` to the div closing just before the footer ie `.content-area` so that the `footer` doesn't cover up your content when the screen height is smaller.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqaVxM

Comment: Also make sure you add padding to the bottom of the body equal to the height of the footer + a little extra so it doesn't prevent the bottom-most content from being unreadable.

Comment: This works but then it is always visible as you scroll. I'd like for it to only be visible once you scroll to the bottom of the page or if the whole page is in view.

Comment: k, I get the question now.  Will modify my answer

Comment: k, try the codepen now https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqaVxM.  I updated it.

Comment: @Ryan Mcguinn did this help you out, or is there still an issue?